# Error for "default_web_client_id" when "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8" is upgraded to "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10"

Tags: android, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I came across a unique error of default_web_client_id for Google Sign Options when I tried to upgrade com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8 to com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() // New line
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

        
    }
}
```

Error goes when I downgrade it to com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8.
What's needed to be done to rectify the issue?

Even App is working Fine. My app is getting Logged in through google despite showing this Error.

Error Screen Shot for more clarification:
[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMuNB.png)

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue also, do you found any solution/workaround aside from downgrading it to 4.3.8?